# Activating the in built web camera on a laptop in .NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to activate the built-in web camera on a laptop for my application using .NET.

Is there any method that I can get this done in visual studio 2010?

Comment: I am trying to do a web application and i am using ASP.NET as the coding platform. The machine i am using is DELL

Answer (score 1):

The [article here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/WebcamUsingDirectShowNET.aspx) shows how you might do so using DirectShow and .NET

But ...

DirectShow on Windows Server 2008 (& R2) is fraught with problems so you might want to consider a different solution if this is the target OS

Comment: Just noticed the ASP.NET tag ... that might cause issue too :S

Answer (score 0):

Touchless SDK (http://touchless.codeplex.com/releases/view/17986) contains a generic DLL for accessing webcams.  Some of the cams, like the Toughbook, require accessing their own API.  The Toughbook also has a downloadable SDK for their camera.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about ASP.NET application? The answer is no unless you use some sort of activeX to be installed on the client browser.